# If statement judgment can not be passed

Tags: android

When obtaining the information of server return, LOGCAT display 1 2 3. Result is 1, 5, 6.

When judge if statement, it has the error. I think the result is 1, but it still wrong.

```
try {
    URL url=new URL(urlstr);
    URLConnection conn = null;
    Log.i("Text", "1");
    try {
        conn = url.openConnection();
        Log.i("Text", "2");
        InputStream in=conn.getInputStream();
        Log.i("Text", "3");
        byte[] buffer=new byte[in.available()];
        in.read(buffer);
        String result=new String(buffer);
        Log.i("Text", "result="+result);
        if(result.equals("1"))
        {    
            Log.i("Text", "4");
        } else {
            Log.i("Text", "5");
        }
        Log.i("Text", "6");
    }
}
```

I don't know why. Could anyone help me? Thanks very much.

Comment: what's your question? Can you be a little clear?

Comment: What's the result of this line? `Log.i("Text", "result="+result);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's unclear exactly what you're trying to achieve, but these three lines have three problems:

```
byte[] buffer=new byte[in.available()];
in.read(buffer);
String result=new String(buffer);
```

1. You should almost *never* use `available()`. Instead, create a fixed size buffer (it sounds like you're not expecting much data, so just a small buffer would be fine.) What if there's no data available when you call `available()`? You'll be creating an empty array - surely you don't want to do that.
2. You're ignoring the return value of `InputStream.read()`. *Never* do that. You have no idea how much data has actually been read.
3. You're creating a `String` from a `byte[]` without specifying the encoding. Don't do that. Which encoding is the data *actually* using?

My guess is that you're *either* passing an empty array in, *or* you're actually reading more than one byte.